# "Pretty good" WPF/Winforms programmer interviewing for ASP.NET job

Tags: asp.net, interview, wpf

I have 5 years of experience writing WPF and WinForms applications. I solo wrote the software and thing always turned out well, and the company I work for has happy customers. Plenty of SQL, EF, LINQ, etc along the way. Things look nice to boot.

I know zero ASP.NET. Neither my job nor personal projects have let me to work with it.

Tomorrow I have an interview for a job that is for an ASP.NET/MVC/WPF/WinForms developer, though I gather from my recruiter that they like to ask about ASP.NET specifically.

Now my question is, what exactly are my strengths here? I know I have a good amount of skills, but will they translate well going to ASP.NEt, in that I should act confident that I could pick it up quick on the job since I learned the other technologies? Any other advice?

For comparison's sake, while I feel that I have a good handle on and am "pretty good" at WPF programming, it took me a while to get the hang of it coming from WinForms. I feel that if an employer had kept a close eye on me during that time, they wouldn't have been impressed.

Any thought? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is a fairly large difference between the the web and native app paradigms. For instance when a page posts back in ASP.NET you loose your variables values. All of the fundamental skills of the techs you mentioned will definitely translate to some extent though, plus they are built on the common MS/.net so there will be a lot of commonalities. I'd suspect you'd be able to answer a decent amount of question.

If you DID get the job it would be a struggle for a bit. But like all things, if you are competent, and if you are smart and work at it, you'll pick it up and be good at it before too long.

I'd suggest be upfront and honest about it. It would be worse if you squeaked by in your interview, only to be let go a couple of weeks later when you get found out.

Comment: +1. Honest answer. *I'd suggest be upfront and honest about it. It would be worse if you squeaked by in your interview, only to be let go a couple of weeks later when you get found out.*